# New Ubuntu 16.04 with no wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

My laptop is Lenovo Yoga 910. I have Ubuntu installed however I cannot connect it to wireless network. Wifi just cannot be enabled. Also since this is an ultrabook it does not use ethernet. I am using dual OS and wifi is on and works fine on Windows 10. Is there any driver I should install? I am completely new to this, please be specific. Thank you.

Comment: Open terminal (CTRL + T) and enter `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`  Does this show a wireless interface and something next to kernel driver in use?  Also check `rfkill list all`  Does it show something blocked?

Comment: It shows Network controller [0280] qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless network adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)

Comment: subsystem lenovo QCA6174 802.11ac wireless newwork adapter 17aa:0827  kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci  kernel modules: ath10k_pci

Comment: rfkill returns help; event; list [IDENTIFIER]; block [IDENTIFIER]; unblock IDENTIFIER   where IDENTIFIER is the index no. of an rfkill switch or one of: <idx> all wifi wlan bluetooth uwb ultrawideband wimax wwan gps fm nfc

Comment: The command is `rfkill list all` not just `rfkill` Thanks and what is the result for `dpkg -l | grep linux-firmware`

Comment: I checked rfkill list all and it shows that ideapad bluetooth and wifi are hard blocked, but hci0 bluetooth and phy0 wireless are not

Comment: and it returns dpkg: error: unknown option -1; type dpkg something something type apt something something and a bunch of options

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a kernel module is blocking wifi, so

```
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad-laptop.conf
```

Reboot and see if the hard blocks are gone

I would suggest filing a bug report at bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu against package linux and then follow instructions

Comment: This worked for me back can you explain in your answer what it does?

Comment: The command keeps the ideapad-laptop module from loading.  A year or so ago a change was made to the rfkill registers in BIOS of some Lenovo laptops/netbooks that falsely reported wifi as blocked with the ideapad-laptop module.  You could file a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug) against linux as your issue may have been fixed with [this commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/commit/drivers/platform/x86/ideapad-laptop.c?id=40c30bbf3377babc4d6bb16b699184236a8bfa27) in the upstream kernel development

Comment: Works on Lenovo Miix 720. There's a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1755094