# Yoga 910 wifi not listing networks

Tags: networking, lenovo

I've just got a yoga 910. But I can not connect it to any network.

I installed ubuntu 16.04.01 and did:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad-laptop.conf
```

However, I can get the list of networks available to connect to any of them.
When I check with rfkill I get:

```
0:hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1:phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I do:

```
iwlist scanning

lo   Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp1s0    Failed to read scan data: Network is down.
```

I get not list of networks in the icon at the top bar of the Ubuntu desktop. I do not know what to do.

Hi,

I tried with 16.10 and worked. I changed back to 16.04.01 and the problem persists.

When I do

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

I get

```
 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
        Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0827]
        Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
        Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Could any one help me please? 
 Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please run the following [script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and [edit] your post with the output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Done, I've already edited

Comment: This is probably a firmware issue. Please add output of `dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: You should take a look there
http://askubuntu.com/questions/847250/new-ubuntu-16-04-with-no-wifi/847282